# How to determine orientation of a EV3 gripper?

Tags: ev3, programming

I have built the EV3 Gripper using the manual.
I am programming an ev3 brick using ev3dev. I need to determine the angle/direction/orientation of the robot programmatically, before I can issue a command to grab the object. How can I get the orientation?

One way to do this I know is to use an external camera to find out what direction the bot is pointing to, I want to do it without the camera.

Comment: How about using a gyroscope, like this one [45505 Ev3 Gyro Sensor](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/EV3-Gyro-Sensor-45505)?

Comment: well, the issue is, here in Singapore, these things are not easy to find :-( and due to shipping restrictions, I cannot have one shipped here as well!

Comment: Can you keep track of the position based on the rotation of the motors during moves?  I know LeJOS (Java for EV3) has a nice waypoint library with pathfinding etc. that keeps track of the position, maybe ev3dev does too?

Comment: thanks for the pointer @Gliderman! i will check that and update it here